# Extract the first letter from each string in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

I got a huge numpy array where elements are strings.  I like to replace the strings with the first alphabet of the string. For example if

> C[0] = 'A90CD'

I want to replace it with

```
C[0] = 'A'
```

IN nutshell, I was thinking of applying regex in a loop where I have a dictionary of regex expression like

> '^A.+$' => 'A'
>
> '^B.+$' => 'B'
>   etc

How can I apply this regex over the numpy arrays ?  Or is there any better method to achieve the same ?

Comment: Do all strings start with a letter or do you want to extract the first letter of a string like `02AC9`?

Comment: yes, all strings start with letter.  But, in effect, I am interested in the first letter of the string.

Comment: Well, then you got your answer from Coldspeed.

Comment: Do all strings have the same length in your array?

Comment: Yes, all strings are same length

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no need for regex here. Just convert your array to a 1 byte string, using `astype` -

```
v = np.array(['abc', 'def', 'ghi'])
```

```
>>> v.astype('<U1')
array(['a', 'd', 'g'],
      dtype='<U1')
```

Alternatively, you change its `view` and stride. Here's a slightly optimised version for equal sized strings. -

```
>>> v.view('<U1')[::len(v[0])]
array(['a', 'd', 'g'],
      dtype='<U1')
```

And here's the more generalised version of `.view` method, but this works for arrays of strings with differing length. Thanks to Paul Panzer for the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48320432/extract-the-first-letter-from-each-string-in-a-numpy-array/48320451#comment83627026_48320451) -

```
>>> v.view('<U1').reshape(v.shape + (-1,))[:, 0]
array(['a', 'd', 'g'],
      dtype='<U1')
```

**Performance**

```
y = np.array([x * 20 for x in v]).repeat(100000)

y.shape
(300000,)

len(y[0])   # they're all the same length - `abcabcabc...`
60
```

Now, the timings -

```
# `astype` conversion

%timeit y.astype('<U1')
100 loops, best of 3: 5.03 ms per loop
```

```
# `view` for equal sized string arrays 

%timeit y.view('<U1')[::len(y[0])]
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.43 µs per loop
```

```
# Paul Panzer's version for differing length strings

%timeit y.view('<U1').reshape(y.shape + (-1,))[:, 0]
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.1 µs per loop
```

#### The `view` method is *faster by a huge margin*.

However, use with caution, as the memory is shared.

---

If you're interested in a more general solution that finds you the *first letter* (regardless of where it may be), I'd say the fastest/easiest way would be using the `re` module, compiling a pattern and searching inside a list comprehension.

```
>>> p = re.compile('[a-zA-Z]')
>>> [p.search(x).group() for x in v]
['a', 'd', 'g']
```

And, its performance on the same setup above -

```
%timeit [p.search(x).group() for x in y]
1 loop, best of 3: 320 ms per loop
```

Comment: Is there an advantage of the view-slice method over the astype approach?

Comment: @Piinthesky I'm not sure actually (just got back making it hella cleaner). I should do some timeits and take a look.... will keep you posted.

Comment: the `.view`-slice doesn't take any extra memory, it's just pointers.  `.astype` makes a copy.  As aside benefit, `.view` should allow you to change those first letters as well.

Comment: Strings needn't be same length for view-casting to work. Just do `strarr.view('<U1').reshape(strarr.shape + (-1,))[..., 0]`, and maybe warn that data are shared.

Comment: @DanielF "_As aside benefit_" or chance to shoot your foot ;-)

Comment: @PaulPanzer That's a great suggestion, I wasn't aware view could do that! And to boot, it isn't even that much slower than the version for equal sizes!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I don't think it's surprising `view` can do that because AFAIK numpy zeropads all strings to the same length. Try `np.array('Hi, I am an example.'.split()).view('<U1')`.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Neat! Didn't know that. Thanks for the info. Will commit to memory.

Comment: what if the string is made of digits ?. In this case <U1 will yield first two digits rt?. How can i get just one digit ?