# How to get the first character of all values out of numpy array (shaped (n, m)) filled with strings

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

So I have a large array shaped like `(n, m)` filled with strings. A small example would be:

```
string_array = np.array([
    ['hello', 'world'],
    ['greetings', 'all'],
    ['merry', 'christmas']
])
```

I'd like all the first characters of each string, but for some reason I'm having struggles. My first guess would have been to use:

```
>>> string_array[:, :][0]
```

Which did not work, because I just take the first row out of my matrix. I want the result that you get when you use

```
>>> string_array[0, 0][0]
>>> 'h'
```

But now for every element in my array? I'd love a solution without loops of course. Just for clarity, I want the following:

```
array([
    ['h', 'w'],
    ['g', 'a'],
    ['m', 'c']
])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract the first letter from each string in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48320432/extract-the-first-letter-from-each-string-in-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `np.vectorize`

```
>>> np.vectorize(lambda s: s[0])(string_array)
array([['h', 'w'],
       ['g', 'a'],
       ['m', 'c']], dtype='<U1')
```

Though please note that `np.vectorize` doesn't actually "vectorize" it applies a function over an array in a loop.

Edit: Looks like this question has [already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48320432/extract-the-first-letter-from-each-string-in-a-numpy-array) and there is a nice performance analysis of other approaches.

Comment: Thanks for that quick answer. So basically it's a concealed for-loop? Edit: from the [documentation of vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html#numpy.vectorize): "The vectorized function evaluates pyfunc over successive tuples of the input arrays like the python map function, except it uses the broadcasting rules of numpy." So it's not really a concealed for loop, since it does use the numpy broadcasting (if I understand it correctly).

Comment: Yes pretty much. However it looks like there other good ways of doing this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48320432/extract-the-first-letter-from-each-string-in-a-numpy-array) I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Ah thanks for finding that! That did not pop up in my Google search beforehand.

Comment: `np.vectorize` might not actually use python level for loops, but the speed is usually worse.  Usually it uses `np.frompyfunc` but with some added generality.  The key is that it doesn't not compile the `lambda` function; that is call once for each element of the input.